# auf den Sprechenden zu

Tags: meaning

Was bedeutet

> auf den Sprechenden zu

Ich zweifele die Bedeutung der Präpositionen im Satz an.

Comment: in Richtung des Sprechenden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Die Wendung

> auf jemand / etwas zu…
>
> <sub>(engl.: towards somebody / something)</sub>

heißt soviel wie „in die Richtung von jemand / etwas“. Hier ist *zu* keine Präposition, sondern ein Adverb, das eigentlich zu einem [trennbaren Verb](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A4fix#Trennbares_Verb) gehört, wie zum Beispiel *zubewegen*, *zulaufen*, *zufahren* und ähnliche.<sup>1</sup> Das sieht man am besten anhand von konkreten Beispielen *mit* einem Verb:

- sich auf den Sprechenden *zu*bewegen
- Du solltest auf ihn *zu*gehen.
- Um auf den Parkplatz zu fahren, müssen Sie erst einmal auf ihn *zu*fahren.

  <sup>(Man beachte den Unterschied.)</sup>
- Werden wir auf die Landebahn *zu*fliegen?
- auf das Ziel *zu*steuern

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Das ist auch der Grund dafür, weshalb ich *zu…* in der Wendung, in der das Grundverb irrelevant und daher [weggelassen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auslassungspunkte#Auslassung_von_Textteilen) wurde, mit Auslassungspunkten geschrieben habe.</sup>

Comment: Ich halte *zu* im Zitat der Frage  für ein simples Adverb, siehe [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/zu_Adverb), Ziffer 2. Damit ist der Zusatz nicht mehr nachvollziehbar.

Comment: Genau der Hauptteil des Verbs, also der Teil, dessen Präfix das Wort "zu" sein soll, kommt im Originalzitat aber gar nicht vor. Daher kann dieses "zu" kein Präfix eines trennbaren Verbs sein.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast, eben. Das Grundverb wurde weggelassen, aber dennoch steht es ja da, sobald man die Wendung verwendet. Das haben Sie in Ihrer Antwort ja auch getan, ich zitiere Sie: „... soll sich auf ihn *zubewegen*.“

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: Zitat aus deinem Kommentar *»Das Grundverb wurde weggelassen, aber dennoch steht es ja da, sobald man die Wendung verwendet.«* Nein, das ist nicht der Fall. Siehe meine Beispiele. Den Satzteil *»... soll sich auf ihn zubewegen«* habe ich in keinem einzigen Beispiel verwendet. Ich wüsste nicht mal, wie man ein Wort wie *zubewegen* sinnvoll in einem der Beispiele unterbringen könnte. Der Teil *»... soll sich auf ihn zubewegen«* stammt aus einer Definition, nicht aus einem Beispiel.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast, in Ihren Beispielen geht es doch gar nicht um die Wendung *auf jemand / etwas zu*, sondern um *herbei*, was aber wiederum mit der Frage nichts zu tun hat. Aber da, wo Sie sie verwendet haben, taten Sie es genau so, wie ich es hier beschreibe: mit einem trennbaren Verb.

Comment: Den Status von *zu* finde ich hier schwer zu beurteilen. Ich glaube nicht, daß man es immer zum Verb schlagen muß. Ein bißchen altmodisch: *wir hatten ein paar grosze zimmer im seitenflügel nach dem hofe zu* [DWB](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?bookref=32,142,14).