# "Nach X zu", alte Zirkumposition?

Tags: grammaticality, grammar-identification

Bei [Novalis](https://www.projekt-gutenberg.org/novalis/sais/sais4.html) habe ich zwei mal die Konstruktion "nach x zu" gelesen. Das erste Mal habe ich mir gedacht, es wäre ein Fehler. Aber zwei Fälle machen es unwahrscheinlich(er). Ist diese Konstruktion grammatikalisch bzw. war sie es vor 200 Jahren? Über weitere Beispiele würde ich mich auch sehr freuen.

> Man hörte Menschenstimmen in der Nähe, die großen Flügeltüren **nach**
> dem Garten **zu** wurden geöffnet, und einige Reisende setzten sich
> auf die Stufen der breiten Treppe, in den Schatten des Gebäudes.

> Er kann dieses Spiel oft gleich wieder vernichten, indem er seine
> Aufmerksamkeit wieder teilt oder nach Willkür herumschweifen läßt,
> denn sie scheinen nichts als Strahlen und Wirkungen, die jenes Ich
> **nach** allen Seiten **zu** in jenem elastischen Medium erregt, oder seine Brechungen in demselben, oder überhaupt ein seltsames Spiel der
> Wellen dieses Meers mit der starren Aufmerksamkeit zu sein.

Comment: Gleiches Thema: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/59235/35111 Die Frage hier enthält gute Gegenbeispiele gegen die Behauptung in der Antwort dort.

Comment: "Zu allen Seiten hin" kenne ich wohl, "nach allen Seiten zu" habe ich im Zusammenhang mit räumlichen Richtungen noch nicht gehört (heißt nix). "Auf etwas zu" im Sinne einer Bewegung schon. Aber vor 200 Jahren, evtl. regionale Besonderheit, warum nicht ?

Comment: Ich würde das als Suffix deuten und versuchen einen Usammenhangzu den mitlerweile geschwundenen Fällen wie den Allativ herzustellen, von dem zwar unklar ist, ob dieser im einzelnen überhaupt Urindogermanisch war, aber es gibt ja noch andere Fälle die dafür einstehen könnten. Vgl. bspw. PSlav "haus": Dative \*dȍmovi, auch \*domovъ (“domestic”) und \*domovitъ (“pertaining to a household”); ebenso *heimwärts*. Gut, das ist Cherry-picked, aber immerhin. In Sanskrit wäre *damat* dagegen Ablativ.

Comment: In älteren Romanen taucht diese Wendung oft auf. Nichts ungewöhnliches für mich.

Comment: @äüö: ja, so sehe ich es auch. Damals war "nach ... zu" statt des heute benutzten "nach ... hin" offenbar auch möglich.

Comment: Das [englische Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nach#Usage_notes) hat ein paar interessante Usage Notes zu _nach_ als Richtungsangabe. Allerdings ist die stilistische Markiertheit von _zu_ vs. _nach_ IMO viel stärker als die Nuance in der Bedeutung.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im [DWB](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GZ08547#XGZ08547) wird beim Wort `zu` unter `c)` die vorausgehende Präposition `nach` erklärt. Entsprechend findet man da auch noch weitere Beispiele. Zusammenfassend steht dort, dass es

1. in Richtungsangaben und damals (siehe "nach heutigem Sprachgefühl") nur bei Ortsnamen oder bestimmten Ortsangaben verwendet wird.
2. in der gelehrten Poesie des 17.—18. Jhs. beliebt gewesen zu sei, auch des Reimes wegen. Dabei wird oft die Bewegung als ganzes gemeint.
3. in Lagebestimmungen bzw. in Wendungen mit einer gedachten Richtung verwendet wird.

Heutzutage höre ich es gelegentlich noch mündlich. Es klingt nicht falsch, aber man wundert sich dann, warum nicht das übliche "zu ... hin" verwendet wird. In älteren Romanen taucht diese Wendung auch oft auf, so dass man es nicht ungewöhnlich findet.