# Does "Er schlenderte auf das Boot zu" contain a "separable verb?

Tags: verb

The text says:'Er schlenderte auf das Boot zu, als sei nichts geschehen'. The question asks: 'In welche Richtung ist der Junge schließlich gegangen?' If the short answer is 'Auf das Boot zu', is the full answer:'Er ist auf das Boot zu geschlendert/gegangen' ? Does it have to be 'zugeschlendert', as if the writer were using the theoretical verb 'zuschlendern', which, like 'zutorkeln, zuhinken, zustapfen, zusausen' and several other such possible "verbs", is not listed in any (?) dictionary?

Comment: The "zu" is not part of the verb. I don't know what that construction is called but "auf etwas zu" specifies a direction.

Comment: Potentially relevant: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/60657/nach-x-zu-alte-zirkumposition and https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/71442/what-is-the-meaning-of-treiben-darauf-zu.

Answer (score 3):

I would agree that "auf etwas zu" is a unit, the techical term would probably be that "auf...zu" is a "circumposition" (analogous to "pre-position"). It can be used as a unit, you mention that the phrase "auf das Boot zu" can be offered as an answer to a "wohin"-question: this is usually considered a test for a constituent.

The trouble is that, simultaneously, "zu"+verb is considered a unit. The form "zuschlendern" does not occur as an entry in the DWDS, it is true, but attestations are shown there, in which *zu+verb* are written together: "Als die beiden Reporter auf den Wagen zuschlendern..." (https://www.dwds.de/?q=zuschlendern&from=wb ) This is in line with the stress pattern: you could not have independent stress on both "zu" and "schlendern", it's always just "ZUschlendern".

Moreover, the completely analogous "zugehen" is listed: https://www.dwds.de/wb/zugehen#d-1-1

So it seems, it can be seen both ways.

Comment: To complicate it further, it can mislead you into thinking it is a zu-infinitiv, but it would have to be double-zu: "Auf den Wagen zu zu schlendern". @Bernhard

Comment: Does the same apply to '(die Straße) entlang', which could also be used with virtually any verb of motion?

Comment: It seems a general tendency that directional particles get sucked into the predicate...