# "hindurch; heran; herum"-composite adverbs or prefixes of verbs

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here are a couple of sentences:

> Er drang durch die Menge **hindurch**.

> Sie trat an den Tisch **heran**.

> Er kam um die Ecke **herum**.

The highlighted words, are these composite adverbs consisting of her/hin+preposition or are these just separable prefixes of verbs? Or can it be either depending on context?

Comment: This seems analogous to the case here: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/75068/does-er-schlenderte-auf-das-boot-zu-contain-a-separable-verb

Comment: The other way of putting the question is: are these words treated as if they were particles like 'aus/an/ein' etc  and therefore written together in the same way? The answer is clearly "Yes"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dependent clauses for your examples so you see it better.

---

> <strike>Du weißt, dass er durch die Menge hindurch drang.</strike>

This is wrong. There is a verb *dringen* but it means *to insist, to press for, to transpire*. None of those meanings match. And neither it is

> <strike>Du weißt, dass er durch die Menge hin durchdrang.</strike>

There is a verb *durchdringen* and it also matches the context but now that *hin* is hanging around, meaning *to* when the context doesn't even imply a destination. So it must be

> Du weißt, dass er durch die Menge hindurchdrang.

That *hindurchdringen* you won't find in many dictionaries and still, it is the only valid verb in this context. It means roughly the same as *durchdringen* but with a slight flavour of *durchstechen*.

---

> <strike>Du weißt, dass sie an den Tisch heran trat.</strike>

Similar here. That *heran* destroys the verb phrase *an etwas treten* with a prepositional object, and for the verb phrase *etwas treten* the accusative object is missing. So this is wrong.

> Du weißt, dass sie an den Tisch herantrat.

This is correct as the verb phrase *an etwas herantreten* exists.

---

> <strike>Du weißt, dass er um die Ecke herum kam.</strike>

This one is especially hilarious because it means *he had an orgasm that way.*

*Don't … ask … why.*

Okay, it's because *um die Ecke herum* is a fixed phrase that means *that way*, and then the remaining phrase is *er kam* which means *he had an orgasm.*

Just remember that you can't use *kommen* without telling the destination. As in *Er kam **her.*** Otherwise it may mean something with orgasms. So it must be

> Du weißt, dass er um die Ecke herumkam.

That's safe. Also note that the verb *herumkommen* has a second meaning *to get around* and a third meaning *to earn* which are both more common than this one.

Comment: *Er kam um die Ecke* is completely unremarkable phrase that doesn't make me think of orgasms. The answer seems to focus on the spelling (i.e. the fact that adverb and verb form an orthographic unit when they are adjacent in final position); but the orthography doesn't say anything about the grammatical relation between those parts. What about *durch die Menge hindurch erblickte er mich*?

Comment: There is no verb *hindurcherblicken*. If you use *hindurchsehen* instead, it becomes ambiguous and you have to do the same investigation on the intended meaning as I did above. It just has the opposite result.

Comment: Also, *um die Ecke* is a destination as *her*.